# For categorical variables with more than two potential values, how are their accuracy measures and F-scores calculated?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, svm

I have a categorical variable say Building Type with possible values (Residential, commercial, Industry, Special Buildings). I applied SVM on the datasets and tried to predict a value of population class (High, MED, LOW) based on building type. how are the accuracy measures and F-scores calculated for my case? Is accuracy measure a good metric for a categorical variable with values more than one?

Comment: It doesn't matter how many categories are present to calculate accuracy or F1 score. `Accuracy = # correct predictions/ # Total predictions` (note that this doesn't look at categories - just the totals). `F1-score` is also derived from true/false positives/negatives , which are aggregate figures of per-class performances.

Comment: Not directly addressing your question, but you might also want to print a Confusion Matrix involving all four classes together. This way you could uncover which classes are hard for your model. E.g. most of you failure cases are being caused by you model predicting Commercial buildings as Industry.